# How to pull out JSON values from Stripe output

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to simply display the 'amount_total' in an  tag from my Stripe JSON output but I keep getting the following error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Here is part of the Stripe output:

```
{
  "session": {
    "id": "cs_test_w3GvxNyitVrBsC6nB8SlaLx6gYxeGD1mVwrTVb0YIx8feZPt1FoBe76IY5",
    "object": "checkout.session",
    "allow_promotion_codes": null,
    "amount_total": 6700,
    "billing_address_collection": null,
    "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/checkout",
    "client_reference_id": null,
    "currency": "usd",
  }
}
```

Here is my React (Next.js) code I'm working with:

```
export default function learn() {

  const handleClick = async (event) => {
    const { sessionId } = await fetch('/api/checkout/session', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ quantity: 1 })
    }).then(res => res.json())
    const stripe = await stripePromise;
    const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId,
    })
  }

  const router = useRouter();

  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    router.query.session_id 
      ? `/api/checkout/${router.query.session_id}` 
      : null,
    (url) => fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
  )

  return (
    <>
    <Nav />
      <div>
        <h1>Payment Result:</h1>
        <pre>{data ? JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) : 'Loading...'}</pre>
        
        {data.map((amount) => (
          <h1>{amount.amount_total}</h1>
        ))}
      
        <button role="link" onClick={handleClick}>
          Checkout
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your "data" variable is empty. So that's why the "map" method/function has error. You don't assign your "data" variable to the data that you get from the url.

Answer (score 0):

The query is asynchronous so by the time your jsx is rendered data is empty.  When fetching data you need to do this in a side-effect, so you would want to run it within a 'useEffect' hook - and then update the data object when it returns.

Look at this article for some examples:
https://maxrozen.com/fetching-data-react-with-useeffect